Using iptables to route TCP traffic to upstream http proxy shows SSL routines::wrong version number
In a dockerized environment without the possibility of having a redsocks transparent proxy, I need to route TCP 80/443 traffic of a container to an upstream proxy, so I enabled net_admin capability on the docker container and used these two iptables rules (also ran for port 80 as well):
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10:6088
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.10 --dport 6088 -j SNAT --to-source $(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')

curl http://icanhazip.com works fine, and prints the IP address of the upstream proxy server but curl https://icanhazip.com shows: curl: (35) OpenSSL/3.0.11: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number.
The upstream proxy is an http proxy. curl https://icahnazip.com -x http://192.168.1.10:6088 works fine.
Update
Using redsocks as transparent proxy:
I followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71099635/7784017 which is taken from this guide: https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/how-to-transparently-use-a-proxy-with-any-application-docker-using-iptables-and-redsocks-b8301ddc4e1e to run redsocks transparent proxy on a Docker container.
So on the container which redsocks is installed, if I run these two commands, curl on http and https work fine and I can see my upstream proxy's IP address:
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 12345
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 12345

This is great, so I mapped my host's port 12345 to the redsock container's 12345 port (-p 192.168.1.10:12345:12345) and now on my app container I ran these two commands (also ran for port 80 as well):
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10:12345
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.10 --dport 12345 -j SNAT --to-source $(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')

And now on the app container, curl on http works but https fails with: curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to icanhazip.com:443.

You cannot just redirect HTTPS traffic to a "normal" HTTP proxy. To proxy HTTPS it expects a CONNECT request - this is what curl -X does. The error you get is likely due to a plain (non TLS) message from the proxy complaining about a bad request.

@SteffenUllrich Thanks for clarification, I thought one possible alternative would be using a transparent proxy, so I updated my question, because I ran into another issue.

Then we discuss a MITM attack. I still don't understand what you want to achieve with this. Why not use a reverse proxy instead of a MITM interception?

@djdomi hi because I want to route all outgoing connections to my upstream proxy, I can't do that with simply http_proxy and https_proxy env vars.

For that engagement, it is necessary to consider the risk of MITM. Any affected user must be informed before using it. There is well-known documentation for Squid, which has the ability for both. did you research it and tried it?
